# Zoombinis level ascension

Tags: zoombinis

How is stage difficulty determined?

I look into my Zoombini map to be greeted by something strange. Some levels are on "Very Very Hard" difficulty, while others are not even close.

"Titanic Tattooed Toads" and others on that path are on red stage; so how can this be when the Mountains Of Despair are only yellow? What constitutes differences in selection?

Is it the amount played at that path (Who's Bayou, The Mountains Of Despair, etc) that determines the color of one of the path's sections?

I'm kind of against the idea, actually, considering this. Before one and after both campsites, the difficulty is different. Currently "Allergic Cliffs", "Stone Cold Caves", and "Pizza Pass" are hardest difficulty, so you can see that the mediocre difficulty of the Mountains Of Despair is quite disappointing.

Another possibility is number of trips made with the most possible amount of Zoombinis (16). My Zoombinis often collide in BubbleWonder Abyss, so I barely ever get 16 across.

Is my problem

- The amount played on one path
- Flawless completion on my task

Or is this something different?

Comment: rhymes? what? no. bad. This is not a forum; if your going to deliberately draw out a question in order to include your own sense of humour, prepare for downvotes.

Comment: That is the worst poetry I have ever read, including that Vogon poem from The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy.

Comment: Fine. Because you insulted my rhymes, I have removed them. Check the edit history to see them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that determines difficulty is the **amount of times you have completed that section**, i.e. run a group of Zoombinis from the first to the third level in each section of the map. The *amount* of Zoombinis you get through does not matter.

The first section and the final section are the easiest to increase the difficulty on, because you will *always* complete these sections on your journey.

The middle sections however, you can choose one *or* the other. Therefore it is entirely possible to complete only one path, therefore keeping it equal with the first and third section, or alternate between the two, keeping the difficulty only half as bad as the first and final sections.

As for the "flawless completion of your task", this actually leads to an achievement: Completing a section of the map, 3 times, with a full group of 16 Zoombinis (1 achievement for each section of the map).

Comment: Because I find the lower section harder, I usually try to increase the difficulty on the upper path because I can use duplicate Zoombinis (unless I want to have ~625 sections on mudball wall.) This way, all on the first sector and the top path are Very Very Hard. The real question here is, why, past Shade Tree, is the difficulty not increasing? It could be your answer, but if so, you might need some more counteracting evidence.

Comment: Yes, it is possible for all Zoombinis to have two features alike, and half have one other feature (such as, say, sunglasses) and others to have a different one (for example, one eye). Counting duplicates, this makes all progression easy! For the upper path.

Comment: @RainbowDash What difficulty is it on past Shade Tree? There are only 4 difficulties, and it *should* be the same difficulty as the first section.

Comment: It is currently orange, while the first is red. Strangely enough, it was yellow before.

Comment: This merely suggests that you have completed the last section *less* times than you have completed the first. This is likely, because "Bubble Wonder abyss" is where Zoombinis go to die-- uhh... teleported back to the Shady Tree Campsite...

Comment: I have. But only 16 Zoombinis are stranded - 14 at one, and 2 at another - And that would not make such a difference.

Comment: You have... what?

Comment: I HAVE completed the last section less times. But only 1 Zoombini trip's worth of Zoombinis.

Comment: This is likely why these two don't match up. as stated, you need to complete each section *3 times* each to increase the difficulty. So in this case, you have completed the first section 3 times on "Not so easy" (or whatever it is), and only twice on the last section, so you will need to complete it one more time to increase the difficulty on that section of the map.

Comment: Ok. I still don't know why it was two levels behind, though. This thing is getting really complex, including things I didn't bother to mention. I 'm playing the old version, levels are always the same after save fraud, etc.